# How do I read a jpeg file send through POST request in Lambda?

Tags: python, react-native, aws-lambda, fetch-api

I have a mobile application which basically sends an image to an API using fetch.

- App.js

```
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
        headers: {   
      Accept: 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "link": uriImage })
  };

  const postExample = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch(
        'https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-x.amazonaws.com/Prod/ocr', requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
          response.json()
            .then(data => {
              Alert.alert("Data : ",
              data);
            });
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

To receive this request I have an API endpoint with a lambda function that basically reads images when sent as raw, which is working perfectly when I test by Postman.

- function_lambda.py

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        body = json.loads(event['body'])
        uri =  body["link"]
        img = io.imread(uri)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        response = "Ok"

    except Exception as e:
        response = "Error"
        
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(
            {
                "response: ": response,
            }
        )
    }
```

I am looking for a way to read a jpeg type file into my lambda function that will be sent via a post request. I made some attempts, such as sending in the body in my request a buffer object of type `Buffer.from(result.assets[0].uri, 'base64')`, where `result.assets[0].uri` is uri from my file. For this I got the following response:

> Cannot understand given URI: {'type': 'Buffer', 'data': [126, 41, 94, 255, 255, 221, 1...

If I send `result.assets[0].uri` directly, I get the following result:

> <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/ImagePicker/b260cf6e--4cd6-b128-.jpeg'>

Comment: Ideally, jpeg should be uploaded to a location in S3, and then link to S3 should be included in request. This is to work around Lambda/API Gateway payload limits, which IIRC is something like 5MB max of raw data.